# EF Core 5 HasDefaultValue FluentAPI

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am trying to set a default value in the context using the following:
entity.Property(e => e.FirstName)
.IsRequired().HasDefaultValue("john")
.HasMaxLength(100)
.IsUnicode(false);

I get an error SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column

It doesn't seem to set the default value on an insert. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

```
public class Buyer : Aggregate
   {
       public Buyer(){}

       public Buyer(int identification, string firstName, string lastName)
       {
           this.Identification = identification;
           this.FirstName = firstName;
           this.LastName = lastName;
       }
       //test
      public int BuyerId { get; set; }
        public int Identification { get; set; }
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public bool BuyerExists()
        {
            bool buyerExists = Identification > 0;
            return buyerExists;
        }
        public override void Validate()
        {
            if (this.LastName == "")
            {
                NotificationHandler().AddNotification(1, "last name cannot be blank1","Buyer");
            }
        }
        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetIdentityComponents()
        {
            yield return this.Identification;
        }
    }
}
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Buyer>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Buyer", "Purchasing");
                entity.HasKey(e => e.BuyerId);
                entity.Property(e => e.BuyerId).HasColumnName("BuyerID");
                entity.Property(e => e.Identification); 
               
                  entity.Property(e => e.FirstName)
                     .HasDefaultValue("john")
                    .HasMaxLength(100)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.LastName)
                    .HasMaxLength(100)
                    .IsUnicode(false);
            });
  public int SaveBuyer(Buyer buyer)
        {
            _techOversightDevContext.Buyer.Add(buyer);
            object identity = _techOversightDevContext.SaveChanges();
            var sqlAutoIdentity = (int)identity;
            return sqlAutoIdentity;
        }
   [TestMethod]
        public void Should_Save_Buyer()
        {
            BuyerRepository postRepository = new BuyerRepository(new TechOversight_DevContext());
            Domain.Buyer buyer = new Domain.Buyer();         
            buyer.LastName = "s";
                postRepository.SaveBuyer(buyer);         
        }
```

Comment: Try to remove IsRequired - entity.Property(e => e.FirstName) .HasDefaultValue("john") .HasMaxLength(100) .IsUnicode(false);

Comment: I tried to remove IsRequired and I get the same error

Comment: Can you post the whole code, how are trying to insert data

Comment: I included the code in the post

Comment: Thanks, but what is this   entity.Property(e => e.FirstName)
                     .HasDefaultValue(DateTime.Now).HasColumnType("string")

Comment: Sorry I pasted in old code. I updated it again

Comment: Thanks, and you have to show  the code where you got the error

Comment: I added the unit test